# Want to know what allth terms in windbg output of "!analyze -v" indicates?

Tags: windbg

What the key value indicates.......and which is the term help me to undersatnd how the windbg bucket the crashes means how it braodly classify the crashes into?

Comment: Most end user facing information on WinDbg can be found in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-the--analyze-extension However, it is a tool for professionals with enough experience on native Windows development and how programs run internally, so you won't easily learn it in a couple of hours. Open a support case via http://support.microsoft.com or buy third party dump analysis services if the issue is urgent.

Comment: I want to build some tools which will make easy to use Windbg or which will help me to analyze tons of crash dumps easily.

Comment: Then your tool should build upon existing tools like `dotnet-dump` https://github.com/dotnet/diagnostics which shows actually how to capture/load dump files and perform automatic analysis on them. That project is very .NET Core specific, but you can still learn enough and reuse as much code as possible.

Answer (score 3):

> help me to understand the windbg bucket

IMHO, the idea of buckets was introduced for WER (Windows Error Reporting). WER was used by Microsoft but was also available for companies. WER included a service where you could log in on a Microsoft website and then get an overview of your application crashes.

Of course, people were not interested in a flat list of crashes, but they wanted to know how many crashes of the same type occured. Thus Microsoft and other company could focus on fixing those bugs first which affected most of the users.

The bucket, as the name suggests, is a container where similar problems grouped. The bucket ID is generated in 2 phases: a labeling process which was done on the client side and a classifying process which was done on server side.

What you get from `!analyze` is the classification, so basically you have access to the functionality via WinDbg that Microsoft used on the server side for providing the WER services.

These WER services are not available any more. They hae been replaced by something else, but I have forgotten the name.

> how it braodly classify the crashes into?

An ideal bucketing algorithm would create a new bucket for each bug. So the number of buckets is just limited by the amount of bugs you can code into your application.

The command `!analyze` has implemented more than 500 different heuristics. The combination of these can create more than 25.000.000 different buckets.

Buckets can differ because of

- stack
- modules
- function name
- function offset
- corruptions (heap corruption, image corruption)
- detected malware
- known outdated programs or libraries
- known defective hardware
- exception codes
- exception subcodes
- ...

The result of that bucketing process is this line of output:

```
FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  BREAKPOINT_80000003_ntdll.dll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak
```

which is probably somehow equivalent to this hash:

```
FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {06f54d4d-201f-7f5c-0224-0b1f2e1e15a5}
```

I have read some of your previous questions in the [windbg](/questions/tagged/windbg) tag and I get the impression that you want to use the bucket ID to display some meaningful information to humans.

Actually, the WER system provided such a feature. It worked like this: a developer analyzes the crashes in a bucket and finds out what to do (e.g. update a driver, install a newer version of the application etc). He then assigns that bucket ID a text. Any customers that experience the same crash again were redirected to a website at Microsoft that contained the text written by the developer.

However, note that there is no magic involved that would transfer a crash into something human readable. That's the developer doing hard work and then creating a mapping from the bucket ID to some text that is displayed.

IMHO, the latter can easily be achieved. However, any new bug will require an analysis first. But, who knows, maybe we can train an AI that does better at this.

For more on buckets etc. please read the Microsoft paper [Debugging in the (Very) Large:Ten Years of Implementation and Experience](http://www.sigops.org/s/conferences/sosp/2009/papers/glerum-sosp09.pdf)

Comment: My end goals are these: Clear recommendations, guidelines & tools to effectively analyse WER crashes for an application 

Create a standalone library that would assist in identifying right bucketing of existing crashes. 

Standalone hang-monitor library to address multi-process application architecture.

Comment: I was trying to understand what the terms in the output of !analyze -v means but not getting any proper description on that. I am not understanding how to bucket them.

Comment: how to do bucketing on my own way I have collected some exceptions like memory access violation, null ptr object accessing member fucntion, some predefined cpp exception to create crash, should I do bucketing like a bucket of crashes belonging to exceptions other one of hangs or should I go deeper that this is a kind of null ptr problem?

Comment: @Prachi: you typically don't do bucketing yourself. That's done by `!analyze`. The bucket is indicated by `FAILURE_BUCKET_ID`as in  `FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  BREAKPOINT_80000003_ntdll.dll!LdrpDoDebuggerBreak`

Comment: @Prachi: of course you could implement your own bucketing algorithms. But probably you're then trying to build something which took Microsoft man years to develop.